# DRF- Post Request Unitest

Tags: unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have a post method under View Set. I need to write a unit test case for the method. when I pass param its give None. How should I pass both param and data(payload).

```
views.py
 @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def complete_task(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
         Method for complete the task
         input post request : task_id : str, variable_return:boolean, request data: dict
         output Response : gives whether task is completed or not
        """
        try:
            get_task_id = self.request.query_params.get("task_id")
            get_process_variables = request.data
            print(get_task_id)
            print(get_process_variables)
            complete_task = CamundaWriteMixins.complete_task(url=CAMUNDA_URL, task_id=get_task_id,
                                                             process_variable_data=get_process_variables)
            print("compl", complete_task)
            return Response({"task_status": str(complete_task)})

        except Exception as error:
            return Response(error)

test.py
    def test_completed_task(self):
        self.client = Client()
        url = reverse('complete-task')
        data = {"variables": {
                    "dept_status": {"value": "approved", "type": "String"}}
                }
        response = self.client.post(url, data=data, params={"task_id": "000c29840512"},
                                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        print(response.data)
        self.assertTrue(response.data)
```

I have tried above test case method which is getting request data but I got param None.
Thanks in Advance,.

Answer (score 0):

if you just modify your request a bit and add query param as part of your url then i guess you are good to go.

**Example:**

```
response = self.client.post(f'{url}?task_id=000c29840512', data=data,
                                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

you can refer the official documentation for the example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/